# Mongo Parse Error URI malformed, cannot be parsed with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to connect to my mongo database gives me this error

```
const DB =
mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0.a4saq7s.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose
   .connect(DB, {
    userNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log(con.connections);
    console.log('dbConnected');
  });
```

This is the string mongo provided
mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.a4saq7s.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

i'm using both the latest packages and drivers, the ip is set to anything. not sure what about this and I am hard coding the uri as well.

Comment: you've omitted username and password

Comment: @dododo i just hid the user and pass